# Wann endet "paar" und beginnt "viele"?

Tags: numbers

Bis zu welcher Anzahl verwendet man "paar", und ab wann beginnt "viele"?

(z.B. paar Autos = ungefähr 5, viele Autos ist mehr als ???)

Ab welchem Zahlenwert ungefähr?

Comment: < 5 => ein paar, > 5 viele: 3456 = > Ein paar Tausend, 8799 => viele Tausend

Comment: Ist 17 viel oder wenig?

Comment: @tofro Keine Ahnung ihr werdet doch gefragt

Comment: Könntest du mir mal die Grenzwerte für so ähnliche Wörter in deiner Muttersprache nennen?

Comment: @idmean https://xkcd.com/1070/

Comment: Es wäre gut, wenn du deine Frage ausführlicher formulierst, wie bist du konkret auf das Problem gestoßen? Dein Beispiel ist nicht gerade hilfreich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich bin mit den Auskünften meiner Vorredner nicht rückhaltlos einverstanden. Es hängt nicht so sehr vom *Kontext* ab, oder "Kontext" ist jedenfalls nicht das beste Worte dafür. Denn "Kontext" suggeriert ja, dass es gleichwohl eine objektive Entscheidung wäre, ob zählbare Dinge "ein paar" oder "viele" sind.

Entscheidend ist hier jedoch deine eigene persönliche Haltung zum Gesagten. Du als Sprecher entscheidest, ob du eine Menge von Dingen als "ein paar" oder "viele" ansiehst.

Diese sprachlichen Ausdrücke sind nicht rein mathematisch-quantitativ zu verstehen. Sie tragen auch eine Aussage über deine Einstellung zum Objekt der Rede. Der Hörer versteht: "Der Sprecher findet, dass die erwähnte Menge eine kleine bzw. eine große ist."

Kurz also: **Du** entscheidest, mit welcher Wertung du deine Aussage schmücken möchtest.

Grundsätzlich - im Sinne von: bei Fehlen anderer Faktoren - kann man aber davon ausgehen, dass *ein paar* vorwiegend für Dinge von einstelliger Zahl verwendet wird. Jedenfalls bedürfte es schon eines sehr speziellen Kontexts (und einer sehr deutlichen Meinungsäußerung dazu), bei Dingen, die in mehr als einstelliger Zahl auftreten, von "ein paar" zu sprechen. (Kommentator "User Unknown" bringt unten aber zwei schöne Beispiele, wo "ein paar" mit Fug und Recht für deutlich mehr als nur eine einstellige Anzahl steht.)

Comment: Auf SSD-Festplatten ist in der Regel ein Bereich mit Reservespeicher untergebracht, so dass man da ein paar Bytes speichern kann, wenn ein Sektor kaputtgegangen ist. - Nicht alle Radfahrer sind Verkehrsrowdies, aber ein paar fahren fast über jede rote Ampel.

Comment: @user unknown und? Passt doch alles

Comment: Was ist der sehr spezielle Kontext, der bei Bytes auf SSDs oder Radfahrern dafür sorgt, dass diese, auch wenn sie zu Tausenden oder Millionen auftreten, von 'paar' reden kann? Mit "einstellig" gehe ich nicht d'accord.

Comment: @userunknown   Teil 1 meiner Antwort war ja, dass es v.a. auf deine eigene Einschätzung ankommt, ob du eine Menge als groß oder klein ansiehst. Teil 2, gleichsam in Klammern, fügte dann noch an, dass im Alltag "ein paar" meistens eher einstellig an der Zahl sind und dass Abweichungen eines besonderen Kontexts bedürften. Mit den Radfahren und den Bytes hast du schöne Beispiele für solche Kontexte gegeben.

Answer (score 11):

Die Annahme, dass es zwischen "ein paar" und "viele" eine Grenze gibt, ist schon falsch. Während "viele" sich auf eine Anzahl größer als "normal" bezieht, beschreibt "ein paar" eine geringe Anzahl oder eine geringe verhältnismäßige Dichte.

Wenn ich mir ein paar belegte Brote fürs Büro mache, und es sind z. B. fünf größere, dann sind das im Normalfall schon ziemlich **viele**. Wenn ich da noch **ein paar** Salzkörner darüber streue und es sind fünf pro Brot, dann hat das mit **vielen** schon wieder gar nichts zu tun.

Wenn der Regen nachgelassen hat, aber **ein paar** Tropfen noch fallen, dann können das auf die Fläche gesehen immer noch tausende oder hunderttausendene sein, wenn ich aber auf die Pfützen schaue, dann landet in diesen nur noch gelegentlich ein Tropfen.

Das Gegenstück zu "viele" ist also nicht "ein paar", sondern "wenige" und zwischen "wenige" und "viele" liegt die Menge, die den Umständen nach zu erwarten ist, also die "normale" Menge.

"Ein paar" bedeutet mindestens, dass es gewissermaßen abzählbar sein muss. Im Beispiel der Regentropfen müsste ich in der Lage sein, z. B. in einem 5 × 5 Meter Becken, die einfallenden Tropfen zu zählen.

Nach "ein paar" gibt es keinen eindeutige nächste Stufe. Möglicherweise kann man da ein knappes Dutzend verwenden, das kann aber auch schon zu viel sein.

Comment: Wegen des guten Beispiels Regentropfen muss ich die Antwort upvoten, auch wenn ich aus 2 Gründen damit Bauchschmerzen habe. Zum Beispiel können Autobahnen dauernd und seit langem verstopft sein, weil da viele Autos fahren. Viel kann also normal sein. Und die Abzählbarkeit mit einem 5x5m Becken ist herbeischwadroniert. So betrachtet ist alles abzählbar - nimmt man eben zur Not  einen Kronkorken und zählt da.

Comment: @userunknown Ich wollte mit dem 5x5m Becken eben genau Deine Argumentation vermeiden. Wenn nur noch ein paar Tropfen fallen, dann kann es sein, dass man im Kronkorken eben keine Tropfen mehr findet. Zuerst wollte ich was mit gelegentlichen Tropfen in Pfützen schreiben, aber da stellt sich vielleicht jeder was anderes vor. 10x10m war mir dann zu groß.  In Bezug auf die Autobahn, wenn Du da von vielen Autos schreibst, dann setzt Du das ja auch wieder in Beziehung zu weniger, bzw. normal befahrenen Autobahnen.

Comment: Autobahnen: Nein. Man kann in einem Land leben, in dem die Autobahnen seit je verstopft sind, also viele Autos normal sind. Was viel ist, ergibt sich hier nicht aus dem Mittelwert, sondern aus der Zahl, bei der noch flüssig gefahren werden kann.

Comment: 5x5m Becken: Das Beispiel wirkt so, als sei die Größe des Beckens willkürlich so gewählt, dass sie zu Deiner Vorstellung davon, was paar Regentropfen sind, passt. Es passt aber schon aufs nächste Beispiel nicht (Salzkörner in der Suppe), noch gibt es eine Vereinbarung über solche Maßstäbe, je nach Fall. Es ist also nicht hilfreich. Außerdem ist 5x5m schon recht groß. Wenn pro Sekunde ein Tropfen pro Quadratmeter niedergeht würde ich "ein paar" sagen, aber 25 Tropfen pro Sekunde kann ich nicht abzählen.

Comment: @userunknown Es handelt sich hier tatsächlich um meine Vorstellung von ein paar Regentropfen, basierend auf meiner persönlichen Erfahrung. Wenn es zu regnen aufhört, dann gibt es eine kurze Phase, in der man nur noch alle zwei oder mehr Sekunden von einem Tropfen getroffen wird. Gleichzeitig hatte ich diese Bild von Pfützen im Kopf, wo die Oberfläche glatt ist, man aber hin und wieder die Wellen eines Tropfens sieht. Das hatte ich versucht in einen zählbaren Zusammenhang zu bringen. Sobald man es nicht mehr zählen kann spricht man nicht mehr von "ein paar".

Comment: @userunknown wenn „viele“ Autos seit langem die Straße verstopfen kann man zwar sagen daß „viele“ in Bezug auf die temporale Häufigkeit normal sei, nicht aber auf die Kapazität der Straße! Mit anderen Worten, die Norm muss nur sauber definiert werden, dann kann man das „normal“ schon dulden.

Comment: @Ludi: Das ist eben tautologisch. Was "viel" bedeutet richtet sich danach, was "normal" ist und was "normal" ist danach, was "viel" bedeuten soll. Eine 8-spurige Straße, die nicht verstopft, würde demnach nicht von vielen Autos durchfahren, solange es nicht staut?

Comment: @Javatasse: Wenn man also bei gleichem Regenfall am Meer steht, wo zigtausende Tropfen pro Sekunde ins Wasser fallen, und man nicht an sein Normbecken denkt, dann sind es nicht mehr ein paar Tropfen?

Comment: @userunknown ich würde sagen, eine solche Verwendung komme vor. Oder würden Sie sagen, die Umgangssprache sei da genauer?

Comment: Ich will nur sagen, dass das Kriterium der Abzählbarkeit nichts taugt, weil man die Fläche immer so klein wählen kann, bis es abzählbar ist oder so groß, dass es nicht mehr abzählbar ist.

Comment: @userunknown "Ein paar" sagt aus, dass die Menge übersichtlich ist. Wenn es um Regentropfen geht, dann muss auch die Menge übersichtlich sein. Wenn in meiner unmittelbaren Umgebung so viele Tropfen fallen, dass ich sie nicht mehr zählen kann, dann würde ich nicht mehr von "ein paar" sprechen. Natürlich gibt es Leute die mitten im Regen stehen und von ein paar Tropfen sprechen. Das hat aber mit dem eigentlichen Konzept von "ein paar" nichts mehr zu tun. Meiner Meinung nach ist Abzählbarkeit durchaus ein wichtiges Kriterium für die Verwendung von "ein paar".

Comment: @userunknown Es gibt schon einen Punkt in Bezug auf "viele" den ich noch nicht erwähnt habe. Das Beispiel mit der Autobahn ist dafür allerdings schlecht gewählt, weil man fast immer eine relative Betrachtung anstellt, sobald man von vielen Autos spricht. Eine verstopfte Autobahn bedeutet immer, dass viele Autos unterwegs sind, auch wenn das an manchen Stellen normal ist. Es gibt aber eine Punkt in Bezug auf "viele" den ich noch nicht erwähnt habe. Zu dem Punkt würde ich aber jetzt zu Bäumen und dem Satz "Auf der Erde gibt es viele Bäume" übergehen und werde meine Antwort entsprechend anpassen.

Comment: Mit der übersichtlichen Menge verrennst Du Dich jetzt aber. Du flüchtest Dich in die "unmittelbare Umgebung", die gar nicht zur Disposition steht. Oben hast Du zurecht ein allgemeines Regengeschehen beschrieben: Der Regen lässt nach, aber ein paar Tropfen fallen noch. Da Regengebiete selten auf die unmittelbare Umgebung des Sprechers beschränkt sind ist das im Regelfall überhaupt nicht überschaubar und natürlich nicht abzählbar, und einstellig, wie Christian Geiselmann meint, schon gar nicht.

Answer (score 5):

Ich kann Pollizer nur beipflichten: Das hängt vom Kontext ab, da gibt es keine fixen Grenzwerte.

Von einer Frau, die fünf Kinder hat, würden wohl viele behaupten, sie hätte **viele** Kinder.

Wenn ich aber **ein paar** Salzkörner in meine Suppe rieseln lasse, können das schon mal knapp 100 Körner sein, sicher aber mehrere Dutzend.

Comment: Das solltest Du mal überprüfen - nicht dass man Dir noch die Suppe versalzt. :)

Answer (score 4):

Da gibt es keine feste Grenze, das hängt vom Kontext ab. Wenn die gesamte Bundeswehr hundert Soldaten hat, kannst du nicht sagen, das seien viele, das sind dann nur ein paar.

> »Ach, die paar Soldaten!«, sagte Wladimir. »Schaffen wir locker!«

Hat dagegen jemand pro Hand sieben Finger, kannst du mit Recht behaupten: »Er hat viele Finger.« Ein Kind könnte sagen: »Hat *der* viele Finger!«

Anders als Dutzend (12) oder Schock (60; veraltet) sind »ein paar« und »viele« relative Begriffe, mit denen je nach Einzelfall immer andere absolute Werte bzw. Wertebereiche verbunden sind.

Comment: Ich weiss, was du meinst, aber mit "Kontext" hat das nix zu tun, sondern eher, mit "was der Sprecher für 'normal' hält"